# How to improve the visibility of stylus cursor in OneNote

Tags: windows, microsoft-onenote, cursor, stylus

I record my lectures on a Windows 2in1 using OneNote. And I have the issue of the tiny dot cursor from the stylus which has been brought up [elsewhere](https://superuser.com/questions/520237/pen-cursor-in-onenote-can-be-hard-to-see-when-using-tablet-peripheral) (as pointed out by music2myear below). The tiny cursor makes it hard for the viewer of lecture to see where I am pointing at. Of course I know where my cursor is because I am holding the stylus; the issue is "Can the viewer know where my stylus is pointing at without anything being written?"

My stylus has a side button which when pressed makes a sizable double circle around the dot cursor. (This happens on any screen, not just OneNote.) This is good except that it very faint and washed out. So, in low-resolution  screen-recordings it becomes a ghost.

My question is "Are there ways of controlling the stylus so as to make this double circle halo effect more visible?"

Comment: The "native" solution is to use the mouse rather than the stylus. Otherwise, this question has been asked before and the answer then was PenAttention as you note: https://superuser.com/questions/520237/pen-cursor-in-onenote-can-be-hard-to-see-when-using-tablet-peripheral

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pen cursor in OneNote can be hard to see when using tablet peripheral](https://superuser.com/questions/520237/pen-cursor-in-onenote-can-be-hard-to-see-when-using-tablet-peripheral)

Comment: @music2myear I left a note on that question and then decided to make it a separate question here. So, when I hold the stylus near the screen a dot is seen. If I click the side button of stylus, a double circle forms around the dot. This effect is very faint. I want to make it bolder. I cannot find what, if anything, controls its appearance or its name.

Comment: I know what you're referring to. Unless the display scaling affects this element, or there is an Accessibility setting I was not previously aware of, as I mentioned there is no "native" solution, but as you've edited that phrasing out of your question, your question is correctly and directly answered in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @music2myear   One solution is to use black background color in OneNote then when you press the side button of Stylus the halo is very visible. In fact even the stylus cursor is much more visible by itself.  I still like to know if there are other solutions, for example by controlling attributes of the stylus directly.

Comment: A problem that arises when using a black background is that highlighting appears to become impractical.

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution is to use black background color in OneNote. Then when you press the side button of the stylus the halo is very visible. In fact even the stylus cursor is much more visible by itself.

A problem that arises when using a black background is that highlighting appears to become impractical.